# Using .htaccess rewrites to treat variables as folder names

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use .htaccess rewrites to create the illusion of each user having their own folder on a website, when it's really just a handful of PHP files that generate all user content (often by pulling from a database):

/members/bob/avatar.jpeg points to /members/avatar.php?username=bob

/members/bob/about.html points to /members/about.php?username=bob

I'm completely lost on how to do this... I've pulled up tutorials on using the htaccess rewrite mechanics, but none of them involve changing /folder_name/variable/file_synonym to /folder_name/file_actual?var=variable. If anyone knows how to do something like that I'd be really interested, because I have no idea where to even start on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^members/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/avatar.jpeg?$ members/avatar.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^members/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/about.html?$ members/about.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^members/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/feed.html?$ members/feed.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

I used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test my work as I went along, to make sure that I was doing everything right. Apparently internal htaccess rewrites aren't allowed on Hostgator's shared servers, so I'll have to wait until I upgrade to really use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+members/avatar\.php\?username=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /members/%1/avatar.jpeg? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+members/about\.php\?username=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /members/%1/about.html? [L,R]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)/(avatar|about)\.(jpeg|html)$ /members/$2.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The URL coming in will look like "/members/bob/avatar.jpeg" and I need an internal rewrite to send it to "/members/avatar.php?username=bob" instead. Your solution takes the latter, and redirects to the former, which is a directory that doesn't actually exist.